# Post thumbnail as div background by shortcode and special post ID

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code works well, if its integrated inside the loop and if you need an "img" as result.

```
/* shortcode for post-thumbnail*/
function post_thumbnail( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<div id="post_thumbnail">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail') . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode("post_thumbnail", "post_thumbnail");

/* Shortcode*/
[post_thumbnail]
```

But I want to **create a shortcode**, that show me the post **thumbnail as a div background** (outside the loop) and I need an option to **add an ID** (for the post ID). Is that possible?

Nice would be something like this:

```
[post_thumbnail id="12"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
// [post_thumbnail post_id=""]
function post_thumbnail( $atts ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '',
    ), $atts ));

    $post_id = isset( $atts['post_id'] ) ? $atts['post_id'] : '';

    return '<div id="post_thumbnail">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail') . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'post_thumbnail', 'post_thumbnail' );
```

Reference read: [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Although, I'd add a check if the thumbnail exists using [has_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/), and if it has, output the shortcode.

**EDIT**

As image background you'd need:

```
// [post_thumbnail post_id=""]
function post_thumbnail( $atts ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '',
    ), $atts ));

    $post_id = isset( $atts['post_id'] ) ? $atts['post_id'] : '';

    if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {

        $image_post_out = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id) );

        return '<div id="post_thumbnail" style="background:url('. esc_url($image_post_out) .'); background-size:cover; min-height:200px;"></div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'post_thumbnail', 'post_thumbnail' );
```

Notice that you need to set the height of an element to have a container width.

You could use [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) to get the height and width of an image, and then set it in the style as the width and height of the container, like this:

```
// [post_thumbnail post_id=""]
function post_thumbnail( $atts ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '',
    ), $atts ));

    $post_id = isset( $atts['post_id'] ) ? $atts['post_id'] : '';

    if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {

        $image_atts = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'thumbnail' );

        return '<div id="post_thumbnail" style="background:url('. esc_url($image_atts[0]) .'); width:'.$image_atts[1].'px; height:'.$image_atts[2].'px;"></div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'post_thumbnail', 'post_thumbnail' );
```

Comment: Big thx for help, but the ID doesn´t work for me ;( ... and the thumbnail is still an <img> not a div background.

Comment: What about the id? if you put `[post_thumbnail post_id="{**your post id with featured image here**}"]` it will work. I tested it...

Comment: Aaaah, thats my fail ... one moment, I only write id="myID".

Comment: Ummm that's not right. And it shouldn't work like that. You put your own post ID there. I put the shortcode in a new page, and pulled an image from different post. Be sure to write `post_id=""` in the shortcode :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help :D